# modifying part of URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've moved my abc folder from **/myproduct/abc** directory to **/myproduct/extensions/abc** on my server.

How can I redirect all calls to `http://localhost/myproduct/abc` to `http://localhost/myproduct/extensions/abc` ?

Ex : if requested URL is `http://localhost/myproduct/abc/pqr.php`, it should be redirected to `http://localhost/myproduct/extensions/abc/pqr.php`

Basically I want .htaccess code that can be placed inside /myproduct folder and if someone requests URL like `http://localhost/myproduct/abc/pqr.php` then it will look for occurrence of /abc/ and replace it with /extensions/abc/
We cannot replace /myproduct/abc/ by /myproduct/extensions/abc/ as myproduct can have white-labelled to yourproduct or myproduct1 etc..

Any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: You don't mention if `abc` and `extensions` are fixed strings or they can be different in each URL. If they are dynamic, ¿what's fixed in the incoming URL? On the other hand, which URL is entered and displayed in the browser. This one `http://localhost/myproduct/abc` or this one `http://localhost/myproduct/abc/pqr.php` ?

Comment: abc and extensions are fixed strings.
Incoming url will be http://localhost/myproduct/abc/pqr.php then it should redirect to  http://localhost/myproduct/extensions/abc/pqr.php

Its not necessary that call to above url will come only from browser. (It can be ajax call etc.)

Comment: Yes. I understand that. The question is made that way to make it as clear as possible, that's all. Please check my answer.

Comment: Hello faa, 
I don't know how your answer disappeared from this post, but it worked as i wanted. Please add your answer so i can rate it and it will be useful for others. Thanks a lot..!! :)

Comment: I undeleted it. I thought it was of no use as you never said anything again. But, thanks for your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vijay,

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# REQUEST_FILENAME should not be file name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# REQUEST_FILENAME should not be directory name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/abc/(.*)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*   %1/extensions/abc/%2  [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/abc/([^\.]+)\.php/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*   %1/extensions/abc/%2.php  [R=301,L]
```

Redirects

`http://localhost/Any/Number/Of/Folders/abc/AnyFileName.php`

To:

`http://localhost/Any/Number/Of/Folders/extensions/abc/AnyFileName.php`

To keep the first URL showing in the browser's addres bar, remove `R=301` from `[R=301,L]`

**NOTES:**

1. If only folder `myproduct/` is needed, like this: `http://localhost/myproduct/abc/AnyFileName.php` The rule will work too.
2. If file `AnyFileName.php`, `pqr.php` for example, exists at folder **abc** in the incoming URL, the rule will be skipped (Makes no sense to have it there anyway). The script has to be at folder **abc** in substitution URL: `http://localhost/Any/Number/Of/Folders/extensions/abc/`.

Comment: Its redirecting infinitely as resulting url also contains `abc` and its again redirecting to \extension\abc.
So its redirecting me to  localhost/myproduct/extensions/extensions/extensions/extensions/extensions......[infinite]/abc/pqr.php

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Which server are you using? Have a look at mod_rewrite in case you are using Apache 2.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html